# Xcode 7 Simulator - "SpringBoard cannot be opened because of a problm."

Tags: macos, ios, xcode, xcode-simulator, springboard

I was successfully using the Xcode Simulator yesterday evening. This morning when I came into work, I didn't change anything, but suddenly, every time I open the Simulator, this error pops up "SpringBoard cannot be opened because of a problem." The same exact thing is also happening to my coworker on his Mac. I've clicked Report and sent a report to Apple.

[image]

Since I didn't touch anything, I can only assume that the problem was caused by some update that happened in the background between last night and this morning. I've tried deleting the simulator devices and adding them back. I've tried clicking "Reset Contents and Settings..." in the Simulator menu. And I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode.

I have:

- **OS X El Capitan 10.11.5**
- **Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)**
- **Simulator 9.3 (SimulatorApp-645.9)**

I have no idea why this would suddenly be an issue. Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem and I have just managed to fix it. I am new to Xcode and only 15 years old however this fix has worked for me.

Basically, I went to the the *general* page of my app and then I changed the *deployment target* to ios 9.2 instead of 9.3. After this, I then went to the main.storyboard page, selected the view controller and then from the standard editor, selected the option for the app to build for the deployment target (9.2).

I hope this is clear enough for you to understand and hope this helps.

Comment: > I went to the the general page of my app... 

What app are you talking about? Xcode? the iPhone simulator?